# Git branches not showing in status bar of IntelliJ after upgrading to 2002.3

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have updated my IntelliJ to latest version `2002.3 CE`

Now I am not able to see `git branches` in the bottom right corner of the status bar.
I can see this feature in `git --> branches`, however I want to see it in status bar and don't want to navigate every time I want to see or do some other operation on branches.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Via a [Bing search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=intelliJ+git+branches+not+showing&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=intellij+git+branches+not+&sc=0-26&sk=&cvid=BA830BD1FF4B4FFCBD76925C871C8EBE), I found [this ticket](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000090784-The-git-branch-bane-doesn-t-appear-on-the-bottom-right-corner). Apparently (quoting from the link),

> Enabling the status bar via the View menu fixes the problem

View -> Appearance -> Status Bar Widgets -> Git Branch

If that's not the case, it appears a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168206?_ga=2.130653455.1853664611.1607504438-1994488723.1607504438) has been filed. I suggest you track it there.

Comment: View -> Appearance -> Status Bar Widgets -> Git Branch.

Comment: Still relevant with 2023.1 version :) For some reason, they decided to disable that by default when switching to the new UI (beta)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I didn't even have `Git Branch` option available among `Status Bar Widgets`.
I realized I had Git plugin disabled. You can check it at `Settings -> Plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I read and did whatever. In the end... a simple Restart of IntelliJ magically did the job!

In my case: Git plugin was enabled;
`View -> Appearance -> Status Bar Widgets` did not include `Git Branch` option;
I had `Version Control` widget instead of `Git` widget;
No git menus whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Git branch from Status Bar Widgets

[Status Bar Widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFTX.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34745171)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Git Branch` status bar widget is not available until you switch `Main Menu > View > Appearance > Toolbar Classic` **ON**.